# Sqlite3: display error Database is locked

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

My sqlite3 database display this error:

```
Array (
  [0] => HY000
  [1] => 5
  [2] => "database is locked"
)
```

I have used php PDO for connect sqllite3 database.I have successfully read from database but cannot update/insert into database. It is always shows above error.

I have tried 777 rights to database and also test with it but got the same result.

I have solved above problem  using `$db->beginTransaction();` and `$dbhandle->commit();`

Now problem is that I have used begintransaction before update query and commit after execute the query.Query return true every time but does not affect in database. any idea about it ?

**Note:** Query took long time to display error.

Comment: Did you perform a search on SO? Just take a look on the right side, you will see lots of question with "*database is locked*" ...

Comment: @j0k I have searched and applied suggestions but got the same result then after I have asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem.

Problem in sqlite3 database.I have used sqlite3 3.6.22 on Ubuntu 10.04, This sqlite3 does not support multithreading so I have tested on sqlite3 3.7.7 version and use Pragma command  read from http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html.

Comment: In my case, it was just a case of Setting a BusyTimeout on the db connection (See http://uk1.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.busytimeout.php ) and ensuring the file/directory permissions were correct for apache.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure the directory where the database file lies has the write permission for the db's user. A temporary file is created when you write in the database.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a busyTimeout to more than 50 ms works for my case ( calling from an AJAX loop a PHP file that INSERT data)

```
$db = new SQLite3('db.sqlite');
$db->busyTimeout(250);
```